# KSH: search string for multiple substrings

Tags: string, substring, ksh

I have a simple way to search for multiple substrings in a single string:

```
if [[ $string = *"string 1"* && $string = *"string 2"* && $string = *"string 3"* ]]
```

(here searching for `string 1`, `string 2` and `string 3` in `string`).

How can I simplify this, so that there is only one check?

I've tried:

```
if [[ $string = *"string 1"*"string 2"*"string 3"* ]]
```

and

```
if [[ $string = *"string 1*string 2*string 3"* ]]
```

Note: the three strings specified here will *always* be in this order, hence why I can simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ksh93, you can use the `&` sub-pattern delimiter.

```
$ [[ abcdefg == @(*bcd*&*cde*&*efg*) ]]; echo $?
0
$ [[ abcdefg == @(*bcdz*&*cde*&*efg*) ]]; echo $?
1
```

Only ksh93 has this unfortunately. In mksh, zsh, and bash, with extended matching, the negation sub-pattern allows for this DeMorgan-like equivalence.

```
$ [[ abcdefg == !(!(*bcd*)|!(*cde*)|!(*efg*)) ]]; echo $?
0
$ [[ abcdefg == !(!(*bcdz*)|!(*cde*)|!(*efg*)) ]]; echo $?
1
```

To test for just one pattern, see [this FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/066)

Comment: The second solution works, thanks. Using my syntax (ie in an "if" statement), the solution is: `if [[ $string == !(!(*"string 1"*)|!(*"string2"*)|!(*"string3"*)) ]]`

Comment: @Wikis You're probably using either a very old ksh, or something other than AT&T ksh. Fortunately `!()` is quite portable to all the ksh-like shells, even ksh88.

Comment: I strongly suspect the former...!